# The Form post null value to the pagemodel

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

trying to submit the commenting form,but the form send null data to my razor page.

it is the html:

```html
 <div class="comment-form-container">
                        <h6>Leave a Comment</h6>
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                <input name="Name" class="span4" id="Name" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                                <input name="Email" class="span4" id="Email" size="16" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="ArticleId" id="ArticleId" value="@Model.articleQueryView.Id" />
                            <textarea class="span6" name="Message" id="Message"></textarea>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span2">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Post My Comment">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

and here is the CsHtml code,when in hover the "comment" i just see the null and 0 value:

```
public class blog_singleModel : PageModel
{
    public ArticleQueryView articleQueryView { get; set; }
 
    private readonly ICommentApplication _commentApplication;
    private readonly IArticleQuery _query;

    public blog_singleModel(IArticleQuery query, ICommentApplication commentApplication)
    {
        _query = query;
        _commentApplication = commentApplication;
    }

    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        articleQueryView = _query.GetArticle(id);
      
    }

    public RedirectToPageResult OnPost(AddNewComment comment)
    {
        _commentApplication.Add(comment);
        return RedirectToPage("./blog_single", new { id = comment.ArticleId });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the actual code, not links to images of it.

Comment: I edited my question dear mike.

Answer (score 0):

`comment.Id` is 0 is because your `articleQueryView.Id` is 0.`Name,Email,Message` is null is because you did not set the values of them in form.I think your code is correct,but you did not set the values.

sample:
[image]

Comment: at first i say thank you.as you see in the image , i do the same,i set the value for id,but it doesn't work.

Comment: `articleQueryView = _query.GetArticle(id);`When debug,the id is not `0`?

Comment: no it is not 0 .